# How to use Google Optimize visual editor for SPA with single URL?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-optimize

I am really new to Google Optimize and I am facing a challenging situation to start with the tool !

I want to make run Google Optimize on a single web page developed with Angular.

Actually, my web is 1 unique URL (x) for 5 different screens (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). So in Google Optimize, I put my unique web URL and then I use the Visual editor to pimp my webpage.

The problem is that  the tool only allows me to change elements of the first screen of my URL... It means that I can't create a variant for screen  x2, x3, x4, x5 ; how I'm supposed to do it ?

Obviously, when I want to add a variant, I am only able to target the one URL I have. And for Page targeting section, I don't find URL, path, host or fragment usefull for my situation.

To complete the overview : I have already implemented virtual pageviews using a datalayer to collect data with GTM and track traffic in GA.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: There's "SPA" in the title, what is it? If you mean SAP software, which one is it, and how is it related to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can data.Layer push an event on the additional screens and use this event to activate a change.

See resource here https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7008840?hl=en

To edit the app click interactive mode (to the left of done) and interact with your app, once your at the screen switch back to editing mode.

Update:

What adding the custom event in GTM does is tell GTM to listen for an event and adding it to activate variant change does is tell optimize your listen for that event but you still need to push the event into the datalayer or it won’t fire. Add the below code to your app when the element appears:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'validarPreguntas'});
```

Or alternatively create a custom HTML tag with the below code and add a trigger of when that form part is visible:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
 'event': 'validarPreguntas'
 });
</script
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse ! I read this documentation and I have understood that an event can activate a change ... but although the change is activated, I can't access to the Page editor / Visual editor to modifiy my screen 2. I'm certainbly doing or understanding something wrong but don't know what... Thnak you for your help!

Comment: The interactive mode allows me to navigate in my SPA and make some changes, great! https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/6211957?hl=en

I'm now facing an other challenge : I have created a variant on my screen x2 but Google doesn't display it... I have tried to activate this experiment with both option offered by Google : page load and custom event (for custom event I put an event I have in my dataLayer) but it doesn't work.

Do I have to user activate.optimize or may I push an different event.name in my dataLayer?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the dataLayer push code as activating by a data layer push should work

Comment: I didn't add any dataLayer.push from Google Optimize for the moment: I mean, I didn't setup / code any dataLayer as `dataLayer.push({'event': 'optimize.activate'})`. In my custom event I put the event name validarPreguntas, it's an event I use in a dataLayer from GTM when the first part of a form hostes on my web is submited. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckb0R.png

Comment: Ok, thank you very much Jesse. I tried it again and it works very well ! You saves my week, I feel really thankful to you :)

Comment: @Jesse and ELT - does this mean that you are pushing a unique event name for each "page" of your journey? For example dataLayer.push({event: "step1"}) on the first page and dataLayer.push({event: "step2"}) on the second page, copying what the url might have been? We are sending virtual pageviews on each step (even though the url doesn't change), so should I send the virtual pageview also as an event name? Thanks.

Comment: @jarrodMcguire - Depending on what you are trying to do, if you push an event name for each page then yes you would use gtm to fire a pageview from the trigger which is custom event equals whatever event name you pushed for each page.